# How to keep only a single active instance of an app on the android device?

Tags: android

I need guidance to solve this problem, I put an app in the play store, but after installed on the device, it happens that if I open the application by the shortcut and return in the play store and open there again, it is getting two active instances. it does not call the instance that is already running and yes it starts another ... which is causing bug in my app, with only a single instance activates the app runs perfectly.

What approach could I use to address this? and prevent the app from being duplicated in the android ... Can you give me some reference?

Comment: In the Manifest you could set "launchMode" attribute to Application and Activity to allow only a singleInstance to be opened. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: @emandt Thank you my friend!
This solved the problem, I put launchMode in singleInstance.
Now it's all right!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use system.gc(); after finishing every intent